# How to package a electron application which is using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

I want to package my electron app which is using puppeteer and distribute it to windows and mac users. After reading the docs of puppeteer I configured the installation of chromium inside my local project repo and I could see the chromium file.

```
const { join } = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, 'public/.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

While launching the puppeteer, I gave the path of the chromium and it is working fine, but when I package my app, it says that it could't detect the chromium.

This is my file structure

```
public/
   .cache/
      puppeteer/chrome/../Google chrome
   electron/
      electron.js
   puppeteer/
      index.js
```

This is my puppeteer code -

```
        const chromePath = os.platform() === 'darwin'
            ? '/../.cache/puppeteer/chrome/mac-119.0.6045.105/chrome-mac-x64/Google Chrome for Testing.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome for Testing'
            : '\\..\\.cache\\puppeteer\\chrome\\win32-119.0.6045.105\\chrome-win32\\chrome.exe';
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: false,
            channel: 'chrome',
            executablePath: chromePath,
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

Even if I make it work anyhow, I don't want to package my application with the heavy chrome app which make my final package size to be around ~500mb

**How could I make my electron app to download the chromium and install it whenever user installs my electron app and set the path whenever launching the puppeteer ?**

Comment: Just use whatever the default darwin path for chrome is there.